# How to install Ubuntu Desktop GUI?

Tags: 14.04, unity, apt, gui, arm

I am trying to install Ubuntu Desktop based GUI
How can I do it without using apt-get command?

My cpu has arm architecture. And it has linux kernel with Ubuntu 14.04 filesystem?

Comment: have you tried `Lubuntu` or `Snappy` ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without apt-get?

Comment: Some apt libraries giving some errors I am also trying solve that issue.In the meanwhile i wanted to check if there are any other way of installing unity GUI

Comment: Install Unity by building from source

Comment: Can you share the link of the source file. I couldn't find it